# MySQL data type with Chinese characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert Chinese characters as input into my MySQL database. What should be the datatype for it? I have already seen that data type should be `NVARCHAR` but my database is not taking it.

Comment: "my database is not taking it" - you mean it's not allowing you to use nvarchar columns, or the data being inserted is wrong? In MySQL I think it's common to use a regular char column but set your database to use utf-8 throughout (or specify it on the column) and your driver should handle the conversion for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use UTF-8 columns for storing non-English characters in your database. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) for some more help.

As it says, use `VARCHAR` to save space.

Answer (score -3):

Follow the below Steps:

Step 1: Download the chinese character from google.

Step 2: Then include it in your fonts folder which is in Control Panel

Step 3: Restart your system

Then it works!!

Comment: ? Which Chinese font? And would that really make a difference passing characters to MySQL?

Comment: Right - that's how to make MySQL Workbench display Chinese characters, not how to store Chinese characters in the database.

Comment: That's more relevant, yes, but I disagree: he should be using UTF-8 columns not BIG5 unless it's a Chinese-specific app.